# Jetpack Compose Textfield OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a standard Textfield and I wanna know when user sets focus in it. is there a way to do that?

I tried to set clickable modifier to trigger the event when somebody clicks on it but looks like it doesn't work with TextField:

```
modifier = Modifier
            .clickable {
                shouldShowSearchKeyBoard.value = true
            },
```

Answer (score 26):

found the answer.

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier
    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
    .onFocusChanged {
        if (it.isFocused) {
            // focused
        } else {
            // not focused
        }
    },
```

Comment: I don't know if `.focusRequester(focusRequester)` is required here... care to elaborate on what it does? The TextField already has focus events naturally on `.onFocusChanged`. Asking because I had the same need these days and I didn't use any `focusRequester`

Comment: I don't see that TextField has the onFocusChanged event.  In my situation, I want to make certain that the keyboard is dismissed when focus changes (i.e., without tapping the onImeAction button).

Answer (score 13):

The declarative-paradigm way is to use the focus state from the TextField's interaction source:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isFocused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()
```

Use this `interactionSource` in your TextField.

```
TextField(
    // ...
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
)
```

Now, you can use `isFocused` state however you'd like.